# Configure "Class List" view to use Level 2 by default?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I'm trying to get the Class List view to default to Detail Level 2. The detail level selection is offered on the upper right side of the page, and it defaults to level one. The detail level controls how many tees are expanded by default.

I want level two because all the interesting stuff is in a namespace. Effectively, I want that namespace expanded.

The docs on the [doxygen configuration](http://www.doxygen.nl/config.html) mention *"class list"* three times, but its only to turn it off.

How do I configure "Class List" view to use Detail Level 2 by default?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer for configuring Doxygen to do this, but you can achieve the effect you want by adding a bit to `annotated.html` in your Doxygen output.

Toward the top of the file, there is a script hook to `init_search` when the DOM is ready.  You can add `toggleLevel(desiredLevel)` here to set the level on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() { init_search(); }); // Before.
$(document).ready(function() { init_search(); toggleLevel(3); }); // After.
```

For a more programmatic kludge you could whip up a build script to run Doxygen, parse `annotated.html` as HTML, append a script tag to `<head>` that calls `toggleLevel`, and then rewrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_index_num_entries).
If set to 2 then all trees will be set to detail level 2.
If set to 1 then all trees will be fully collapsed (detail level 1).
If set to 0 then all trees will be fully expanded.

PS: This answer is for those who stumble upon this page in the future.